# Improper use of return functions?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with calling my functions in my `maincpp`
I have header files that have the prototypes but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. It works fine when it is like this but when I put something like       enter code here it says something like `openStore();` it would say none were called and if the variable is intended. I keep going back thinking I finally got it but it seems like I don't.

```
#include "inventory.h"


int main()
{
    Book openStore();
    Book showStore();
    Book getSales();
    Book showSales();




    cout << endl << "End of Program." << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need your prototypes OUTSIDE the main function. Then you main function has to actually call them. You should read through some C++ tutorials; they should be able to get you going on how to use functions.

Comment: Actually, the prototypes need not be outside the function.  It is valid to do what the OP is doing, **but**, those are just prototypes, not function calls.

Comment: Why not post the code that *doesn't*  work fine instead? Your description of it is very vague.

Comment: @Andrew oh no, I do know that. That my prototypes are outside of the main function. I was wondering if I was just using it right but apparently I was not. I have header files that have all my prototypes.

Comment: @molbdnilo sorry about that. This is my first time posting and I didn't know what would be "ok" to post.

Comment: @LEE -- Read my comment.  It is perfectly valid to have prototypes inside of functions.  The problem is that you thought that the code you posted actually called functions.  It does not.  All you wound up doing is move the  prototypes someplace else (that's valid).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ahh gotcha. Thank you.

Comment: @LEE Also in the future post as little as code as possible, that's needed to re-produce the problem. Also if you get any errors from the compiler, then make sure to include them in your post as text in a code block.

Comment: @tambre thank you and sorry about this. I am pretty new to this community.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
#include "inventory.h"
Book openStore();
Book showStore();
Book getSales();
Book showSales();

int main()
{
    cout << endl << "End of Program." << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```